# How to display difference of dates in appearing in consecutive lines in Linux Shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I have output like this :

```
$ cat newdata1| awk 'BEGIN { FS = "+" } ; { print $2"~"$1"+"$2 }'|sort -k1,2|cut -d "~" -f2
[2015-09-11 14:42:18,053] [threadExecutor-7] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeEverything NEW_CUSTOMER - userId - mdmId - InteractionId are + eneblett:0null:null
[2015-09-11 14:42:57,655] [threadExecutor-8] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - afterEverthing NEW_CUSTOMER - userId - mdmId - InteractionId are + eneblett:835808        :null
[2015-09-11 14:46:03,264] [threadExecutor-5] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeEverything NEW_CUSTOMER - userId - mdmId - InteractionId are + tahicks:0null:null
[2015-09-11 14:46:40,407] [threadExecutor-5] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - afterEverthing NEW_CUSTOMER - userId - mdmId - InteractionId are + tahicks:835811        :null
[2015-09-11 14:40:03,264] [threadExecutor-5] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeEverything NEW_CUSTOMER - userId - mdmId - InteractionId are + zz:0null:null
[2015-09-11 14:40:57,655] [threadExecutor-8] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - afterEverthing NEW_CUSTOMER - userId - mdmId - InteractionId are + zz:835800        :null
```

Now, I have requirement to display time difference in seconds after beforeEverything and afterEverthing transaction (lines 1-2, 3-4, 5-6 and so on):

Example of desired output :

```
[2015-09-11 14:42:18,053] [threadExecutor-7] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeEverything NEW_CUSTOMER - userId - mdmId - InteractionId are + eneblett:0null:null
[2015-09-11 14:42:57,655] [threadExecutor-8] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - afterEverthing NEW_CUSTOMER - userId - mdmId - InteractionId are + eneblett:835808        :null
Time for transaction in Seconds : 39 
[2015-09-11 14:46:03,264] [threadExecutor-5] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeEverything NEW_CUSTOMER - userId - mdmId - InteractionId are + tahicks:0null:null
[2015-09-11 14:46:40,407] [threadExecutor-5] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - afterEverthing NEW_CUSTOMER - userId - mdmId - InteractionId are + tahicks:835811        :null
Time for transaction in Seconds : 37 
[2015-09-11 14:40:03,264] [threadExecutor-5] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeEverything NEW_CUSTOMER - userId - mdmId - InteractionId are + zz:0null:null
[2015-09-11 14:40:57,655] [threadExecutor-8] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - afterEverthing NEW_CUSTOMER - userId - mdmId - InteractionId are + zz:835800        :null
Time for transaction in Seconds : 54
...
```

Precision of millisecond is NOT needed

May be we can use some date manipulation like : t=$(date -d "2012-10-12 11:48:30" +%s);t1=$(date -d "2012-10-12 13:13:48" +%s);diff=$(expr $t1 - $t);echo $diff
But I don't know How to use this along with previous piece of commands.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have (or can get) GNU awk?

Answer (score 1):

GNU awk has builtin time functions:

```
gawk -F'[][]' '
    function totime(datestring,       a,time) {
        split(datestring, a, ",")
        return(mktime(gensub(/[-:]/, " ", "g", a[1])) + a[2]/1000)
    }
    {print}
    /beforeEverything/ {startTime = totime($2)}
    /afterEverthing/ {print "Time for transaction in seconds: " (totime($2) - startTime)}
    # .......^^ note typo in your log.
' log
```

```
[2015-09-11 14:42:18,053] [threadExecutor-7] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeEverything NEW_CUSTOMER - userId - mdmId - InteractionId are + eneblett:0null:null
[2015-09-11 14:42:57,655] [threadExecutor-8] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - afterEverthing NEW_CUSTOMER - userId - mdmId - InteractionId are + eneblett:835808        :null
Time for transaction in seconds: 39.602
[2015-09-11 14:46:03,264] [threadExecutor-5] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeEverything NEW_CUSTOMER - userId - mdmId - InteractionId are + tahicks:0null:null
[2015-09-11 14:46:40,407] [threadExecutor-5] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - afterEverthing NEW_CUSTOMER - userId - mdmId - InteractionId are + tahicks:835811        :null
Time for transaction in seconds: 37.143
[2015-09-11 14:40:03,264] [threadExecutor-5] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeEverything NEW_CUSTOMER - userId - mdmId - InteractionId are + zz:0null:null
[2015-09-11 14:40:57,655] [threadExecutor-8] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - afterEverthing NEW_CUSTOMER - userId - mdmId - InteractionId are + zz:835800        :null
Time for transaction in seconds: 54.391
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn..Much appreciated your help here..This should meet my requirement. Let me use it inside my script. Thanks

Comment: Hi Glenn, 

The Solution provided worked well. Thanks for that. I need to include 1 more change here that I need o print, time and userId along with transaction time. For example, the current output is as :   

[2015-10-28 12:38:05,472] [threadExecutor-1] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - afterEverthing UPDATE CUSTOMER - userId - mdmId  kaallen:359510        
Time for transaction in seconds: 4.549.  

I need o display :
Time for transaction in seconds: 4.445:kaallen:2015-10-28 11:33:05,371.

Much appreciate your help in this. 

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F '[\\[\\- ,:\\]]' 'function t(){return mktime($2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7)}NR%2{a=t()}!(NR%2){$0=$0"\nTime for transaction in Seconds : "t()-a}1' Filename
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 1):

```
while read -r  l;
  do
    echo $l;

     DATE2=`echo $l | awk '{print $1" "$2}'| sed -r 's/\[|\]|,.*//g'` && DIFF=$(( $(date -d "$DATE2" +%s) - $(date -d "$DATE1" +%s) )) ;
    if [ "${DIFF}" -lt '0' ] ; then
        DATE1=${DATE2};
    else
        echo "Time for transaction in Seconds :${DIFF}";
        DATE1='0';
        DIFF='-1';
    fi
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would be better of writing a python script that reads the file, sorts the lines, does all the outputting and finally add a datediff line where needed.

However, the the easiest solution I can come up with building on what you have would be adding anothe pipe ("|") and adding yet another awk, that sets a variabele to the ate of col 1 and 2 for beforeEverything lines and writing timediff lines after afterEverything lines. Something like adding

```
| awk 'BEGIN{FS="]"}
{print $0}
/beforeEverything/{f=$1;sub(/[\[\-\:]/," ", f);f=mktime(f)}
/afterEverything/{a=$1;sub(/[\[\-\:]/," ", a);a=mktime(a);printf("Time for transaction in Seconds : %i", a-f)}'
```

Or something?

Comment: Thanks Sebastiaan for your reply however after piping the above code just prints lines as it is.Let me experiment with it anyways. Thanks